# Jsonp doesn't works with Safari in a local net

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, jsonp

For a very custom project I needed to interface a webapp running in a browser with a desktop in the same local net, so created a listenig Socket in c# on the desktop, that responds to ajax calls from the webapp with Jsonp.

It works on any browser (so basically the code must be right), but Safari mac/ipad/iphone.

I've searched a lot and the only relevant solution was to delete the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag, but still it thrown a timeout error and an xhr.status = 0.

There's some particular setting that I need to activate just for Safari?

This is the code that I use to call the Socket

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url_desktop,
        async:true,
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 10000,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try setting the content type, like so: `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: It doesn't work either :( 
I hadded headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"} too

Comment: What error do you get in console?

Comment: Just timeout, for sure with default JS settings Safari blocks or misinterpret the response

Comment: Calling the url directly and not with ajax finally gave me an error! Resource interpreted as Script but transfered as MIME text/plain